# Почему длину среза в Golang нельзя расширить влево?

Tags: golang

Почему вместимость среза безвозвратно режется именно с левой стороны?
Например из учебного [тура](https://go-tour-ru-ru.appspot.com/moretypes/11) можно понять, если мы срежем изначальный массив/срез с

```
arr := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

до

```
arr = arr[:0] // []
```

его значения можно будет восстановить до исходного вида

```
arr = arr[:5] // [1 2 3 4 5]
```

а вот если мы этот же массив/срез срежем с левой стороны, например

```
arr = arr[5:] // []
```

то восстановить его уже нельзя

Чем обуславливается такая механика? Почему бы не сделать обратную индексацию как в Python например?

Comment: Наверно дело в смене индексов, что эта процедура необратима. Когда справа срезаешь, то индексы остаются прежними, а когда слева, то индексы уменьшаются на количество дропнутых элементов. В Python, к слову, нельзя восстановить переопределенный массив

Answer (score 0):

Go срез это структура с тремя полями: указатель на начало массива, размер и вместимость. Размер и вместимость дают информацию о зарезервированом месте для правой части массива.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. отсутствует информация о зарезервированом месте в левой части массива. Следовательно неизвестно как расти на лево.

Почему так? .... Так решили создатели.

На счёт обратной (негативной) индексации [ответ](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11245) команды Го:

> это намеренное решение команды

Comment: Иначе нужно было бы ещё 4 элемент в структуру добавлять. И это все бы сильно усложнило логику расчета элемента по индексу.

Comment: Также для нас это было бы сложно... "Записывал ли я уже в этот массив, через другой слайс?"